# Need to add admin custom claim while using Next-Auth with Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication, next.js13, next-auth

I have a website using Next.js 13 and Firebase Authentication with Next-Auth.  I would like to add a custom claim {role: 'admin'} for admin users, but I am unsure how to do that using Next-Auth. This is what I have in "/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts"

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: '/dashboard/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token = { ...token, role: 'admin' };
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return { ...session, token: { ...token, role: 'admin' } };
    },
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req): Promise<any> {
        try {
          const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            (credentials as any).email || '',
            (credentials as any).password || '',
          );

          return userCredential.user || null;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('===> error:', e);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

What I have right now does not pass security rules such as this one:

```
request.auth.token.role == 'admin'
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks